# Why is Error Message Box occurring with no error?

Tags: ms-access, vba

The code I wrote looks in two locations for a specific file folder.  If it cannot find the folder I want the error message to let people know the file has not been digitized.  However, the Error message is displaying even if the folder is found.  How can I get the final error message to only appear when there is an actual error.

```
Private Sub Command128_Click()

    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "w:\EDU UNDERGRADRecords\Cert Majors\Level 1\"
    sPath = sPath & Screen.ActiveForm![DigitalFile] & "\"

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.FollowHyperlink sPath

    Dim sPath2 As String

    sPath2 = "w:\EDU UNDERGRADRecords\Cert Majors\Level 2\"
    sPath2 = sPath2 & Screen.ActiveForm![DigitalFile] & "\"

    On Error GoTo Error1
    Application.FollowHyperlink sPath2

Exit_Command128_Click:

    Exit Sub


Error1:
     MsgBox "Student File has not been digitized"
     Resume Exit_Command128_Click:

End Sub
```

Comment: It runs because the code does not exit procedure before that line, the code simply executes every line. Here's another reference on error handling code http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23a.html. However, you could possibly get by with a simple `If Then Else`; such as `If Dir(<path string here>) = "" Then MsgBox "some message" Else <your code to do something> End If`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working correctly, the way that it is currently setup. The way that it is setup is to always run in every scenario, since there is no break or exit inbetween the current setup.

However, this would definitely be easier to control with an `IF` statement for this scenario.

Like so:

```
...

sPath2 = "w:\EDU UNDERGRADRecords\Cert Majors\Level 2\"
sPath2 = sPath2 & Screen.ActiveForm![DigitalFile] & "\"

If Dir(sPath2) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Student File has not been digitized"
Else
    Application.FollowHyperlink sPath2
End If

End Sub
```

Additionally, if you wanted to do the same to the previous called statement, do it like this:

```
...
sPath = "w:\EDU UNDERGRADRecords\Cert Majors\Level 1\"
sPath = sPath & Screen.ActiveForm![DigitalFile] & "\"

If Dir(sPath) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Student File has not been digitized"
    'Exit Sub 'An ejection (if required for a single failure)
Else
    Application.FollowHyperlink sPath
End If
```

FYI - You only made the declaration of `sPath`, but not `sPath2`